# Memory usage of DotNET app

Tags: memory, unmanaged, managed

My application (DotNET) runs as a plug-in inside a C++ standalone app that exposes a C++/CLI SDK.

It is very easy for my users to generate large amounts of data and I'd like to offer an abort option if the memory consumption of my plug-in + the base application reaches -say- 90% of the legal maximum.

How can I measure the total memory consumption (ideally for both the managed *and* unmanaged code) and how do I know how much memory windows allows for the current application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Process class provides most of this information.  I think what you're after would be [Process.PrivateMemorySize64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64.aspx).

You should be able to do:

```
var memoryUsage = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
```

Comment: Yes! That's it! I was already worried I had to go through PInvoke to get to this.

Comment: The Process class has many nice metrics like this - take a look at the docs, and you'll see many of them.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a profiling tool: [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/download/) works really well.

Comment: What I need is a way for my application to know how much memory it's using at runtime. I'm not looking for a profiling app.

Essentially, what I want is the number of Private Bytes used by my process as visible in the Process Explorer / Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

[`GetProcessMemoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219(VS.85).aspx) and check the `PrivateUsage` in the [`PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684874(VS.85).aspx).

**Update**

Obviously I misred the question and though you want the value from the CLI SDK side of the app. In the managed side, you already got the correct answer.